# Substring that exits between a recurring patern

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

My string is :`<div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div><br></div>`

I need to get 2,3,4,5,
 in an array using Javascript ie.anything between `<div></div>`

Whats the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: If input does not contain `1` how do you expect to extract `1`?

Comment: My Bad! missed that . Also instead of integers it can be any character available on the keyboard.

Comment: See my update. It is most faster way.

Comment: Why don't you use DOM parsing? You ask what's the most "elegant" way to do this, well... processing an an string instead of using jquery's `$(element).html()` isn't very elegant.

Comment: Actually i actually do not have the DOM structure. I receive a string only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match **anything** between `<div>` and `</div>`

```
var a, r=[];
while((s=str.indexOf("<div>"))!=-1){
    e=str.indexOf("</div>"); 
    a=str.substring(s+5, e); 
    if(a) r.push(a);
    str=str.substr(e+6);
}
```

Another easier method

```
 var r = str.match(/<div>.*?<\/div>/gi).map(function(i){
     return i.replace(/<div>(.*?)<\/div>/gi, "$1");
 });
```

If it was just digits (like in your initial question) use this

```
var str = "<div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div><br></div>";
var num = str.match(/\d+/g)
```

Comment: Wat if instead of integers it can be anything. Alphabets, numbers, *()&^%$# etc.?

Comment: Then you have to specify that in question.

Comment: Does not work.r = 
["2</div><", "3</div><", "4</div><", "5</div><", "<br></div>"]

Answer (score 0):

try the below code

```
var obj = $("div").map(function(index,value){
return $(this).html();

})    
alert( "hi" +obj[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F9MQr/12/

Comment: Hey this works only for actual divs i guess. Actually i have a string not the actual divs!

Comment: Could you please let me know what you mean by "But i hope this does not require a div to be created or itself is not creating one! "

Comment: I actually edited my comment. My question is when i get this statement. You have actually created divs and solved the question. In actual i have only a string

Answer (score 0):

For any value you could;

```
var s = "<div>2</div><div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div><br></div>";
var a = [];
$.each($(s).filter("div"), function() {
       $(this).text() !== "" && a.push($(this).text());
});
alert(a);
​
```

(This would ignore empty divs & return `X` for `<div>X<br/></div>`)

Comment: Actually I do need this <br> also with the X